# Firestore: Store data in 1 collection or replicate for each user?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For a collection where users need to all read from 1 collection, is it better to replicate the collection across all users (and maintain similarity with cloud function triggers) or is it better to just have 1 collection and delineate the read/write access to it via security rules?

The context is a group chat app. For most of a single user's info, I am already going to store this in their own collection. However, for the group info where any numbers of users can be in it (with 1 unchangeable admin), all of the members will need this information. It would be more expensive to replicate and make 1 group record for each member, but the benefit would be that I could keep the security rules simple in that everyone could just read/write to a collection that they "own" (because I would put their copy of the collection as a sub-collection under their user collection record). Alternatively, it would be cheaper to keep a group's information in only 1 collection, but the problem is that I don't know how to define security rules for it that would be safe enough to deploy in production.

**Idea 1:**

[image]

In this idea, any changes to the group record for `uid1` will be pushed out to all other similar records in the groups collection of other users. Pros: security rules are simple because the admin can read/write to their own and everyone else can only read their own. Cons: data is replicated and cost is higher than if I were to store the data in 1 single place

**Idea 2:**

[image]

In this other idea, the data is not replicated. Instead, the data only exists in 1 location and security rules determine who can read and who can write. Pros: data is only written once. Cons: Not sure if this can even be enforced via security rules.

Comment: The difference will be the cost of writing (duplicating) the documents. Writing specific security rules does not seem very complex in the light of the few elements you share in your question. But to help you further we need more details on your requirements

Comment: So to help you further we need details on how do you link a user to a specific group? Is it based on a list of group users in a Firestore document?

Comment: Is it possible to explain your issue with points like snapshot of your DB, what is your goal , what you have tried, what does not work. Any error occurred and lastly steps to recreate your issue.

Comment: Can you please provide the information Renaud and Rohit asked for? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @RenaudTarnec added the 2 ideas I am considering.

Comment: @RohitKharche it's more so that I'm trying to find the most cost effective way to store group information in Firestore and chat information in Realtime Database.

Comment: This question is going to be tough to answer because there are too many variables; how cost effective it is depends on the queries being run, not the number of collections that exist. e.g. If there are 10 collections and 1 doc is read from each vs. one collection and 10 docs are read, the cost is the same. See [Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing) - look at the Document Reads pricing; $0.0345 per doc. That's the pricing whether you have 1 or 100 collections. The *only* difference is that you are charged for the amount of data that you store. Double the data = double the charge.